# LinkedList AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working on the Codewars Kata on linkedLists, and keep getting the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None`

def push(head, data):
    if data == None: return
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next = head
    head = new_node

def build_one_two_three():
    head = None
    push(head, 3)
    push(head, 2)
    push(head, 1)
    return head
```

I thought using the `if data == None` would fix the problem but it didn't. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When/where does this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the line `head = new_node` in your push function is replacing the local reference that head is pointing to, not the data that head refers to in your build_one_two_three function. Try having push return head, and updating your build_one_two_three where each push updates the referece: `head = push(head,1)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something in the lines of:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

def push(head, data):
    if data == None: return
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next = head
    head = new_node
    return head

def build_one_two_three():
    head = None
    head = push(head, 3)
    head = push(head, 2)
    head = push(head, 1)
    return head
# Just to pretty-print the linked list.
def pp(head):
    res = ""
    node = head
    while node != None:
        res += "%s -> " % node.data
        node = node.next
    res += "None"
    print res

if __name__ == "__main__":
   head = build_one_two_three()
   pp(head)
```

The problem is that you are overwriting the reference to `head` every time you push a new node.